# Android intent filter inner links multiple action

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, intentfilter

For my I app I got three different inner links:
myapp://user/id
myapp://album/id
myapp://message/id

So, when appear a text with inner links like "Jonh write you a message", you can click on John and message. If you click on John you go to his profile. If you click on message you go to the message.

I create intent-filter for each activity (ActivityUser, ActivityAlbum, ...) like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityAlbum" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:pathPattern ="/album"
                android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityUser" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:pathPattern ="/user"
                android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The problem is, when user click on a link appear "Complete action using" and appear my app three times (one for each intent).

How I can filter the url for only one Activity?

```
Link   myapp://user/5 -> only for intent  ActivityUser
Link   myapp://message/44  -> only for intent ActivityMessage
etc
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use a different scheme? Like myapp_album and myapp_user.

Comment: Yes, I thought this, but I hope exists a more rigth way

Comment: Documentation indicates that `pathPattern` is only used if both the `scheme` and `host` are specified. Try adding `android:host="*"`. Also, you want to use `pathPrefix` instead of `pathPattern` because you just want to match the beginning of the path.